# Select everything inside contrast border in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

So, i have black and white graphics like this. I want to select everything within drawn square border precisely. In general border can be any shape, it's just a single color closed line loop. So, how can i achieve this?
[image: Photoshop sample contrast image]

I tried:

1. Square selection. I cant aim at the corners of the rectangle with my mouse precisely enough, the resolution is too high to do this.
2. Lasso. Same problem basically
3. Quick select. Objects inside are too contrast, so it works bad here. Also selects area outside border if i barely touch it
4. Magic selection. It does can select the border itself, but not the insides.

Comment: You mean you need a simple rectangular marquee selection just inside one border rectangle - but you think you don't have enough space to be accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you need a simple rectangular marquee selection just inside one border rectangle - but you think you don't have enough space to be accurate…

Just zoom the image to one corner [alt/scrollwheel] then start your selection & just keep dragging - the image will auto-scroll until you can reach the opposite corner…

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's an option. But what if border is not rectangle?

Comment: You can multi-select with any of the selection tools, shift adds, alt subtracts.